# cannot move out of *** which is behind a shared reference (Clap)

Tags: rust, clap

I'm learning rust and would like to better understand what is happening here. I have the following declared:

```rust
pub struct SomeHandler {}

impl SomeHandler {
    pub fn configure(&self, app: &App) {
        app.subcommand(
            SubCommand::with_name("server-status")
                .about("Displays the status of the server")
        );
    }

    pub fn check_match(&self, matches: &ArgMatches) -> bool {
        matches.subcommand_matches("server-status").is_some()
    }

    pub fn handle(&self, arg_match: &ArgMatches) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then in `main.rs` I'm calling it like this:

```rust
    let mut app = App::new("My CLI")
        .author("Author <author@email.com>")
        .version("0.1.0")
        .about("Command line interface app");

    let myhandler = SomeHandler {};
    myhandler.configure(&app);

    let matches = app.get_matches();

    let matched = myhandler.check_match(&matches);

    if !matched {
        eprintln!("None of the commands match the provided args.");
        process::exit(1);
    }

    myhandler.handle(&matches);
    process::exit(0);
```

But I get the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*app` which is behind a shared reference
  --> cli\src\some_handler.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         app.subcommand(
   |         ^^^ move occurs because `*app` has type `App<'_, '_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How do I fix this error? Is there a better way to handle this? I'm trying to build a command line application in rust with multiple commands and options. I don't want to implement it all in a single file. What is a good pattern to follow here?

Any help would be great,

Thanks,
Manthan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`subcommand()`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.App.html#method.subcommand) method consumes the app and returns a new one. This nicely supports chaining, but requires your `configure` function to also accept an object, and also to return one:

```
pub fn configure(&self, app: App<'static, 'static>) -> App<'static, 'static> {
    app.subcommand(
        SubCommand::with_name("server-status")
            .about("Displays the status of the server")
    )
}

// and in main:
app = myhandler.configure(app);
```

It's also possible for `configure` to take a reference, but then that has to be a `mut` reference, and you have to call `mem::replace` to extract the `Clap` out of the reference, leaving a dummy in its stead, and finally assign it back. If you're really curious, take a look at it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fdd816452cfca58a4734297e91034c0e).

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. Maybe I don't understand static lifetimes but I thought if a lifetime was static it will be kept in memory throughout the lifetime of the runtime. Isn't that a bad thing? Or is it that if I use static lifetime for a parameter its static for the lifetime of the function?

Comment: @ManthanDave Yes, `'static` means lives as long as the program - but that's not a bad thing, it typically just refers to data in string literals which are stored in the executable and not dynamically allocated. The two lifetimes in `clap::App` document the lifetime of references to the name of the program of arguments, and in a typical application both are specified with string literals, so `'static` is fine. You can also support arbitrary lifetimes by [adding them](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=914928dfd30525e45df63205ba50de05) to `configure`.